# Listener "Monitor result" not present in Jmeter 5.1.1

Tags: jmeter

In a fresh install of Jmeter 5.1.1 (on Ubuntu 16.04) some functions are not present:

1. There is no "Monitor result" in the listener choices
2. There is no drop-down menu in the "view results tree" to view the response data as html, json, text, xml, etc.

Both are not present at all.

Thanks a lot for any hint on how to get this fixed.

Regards, 
Fabianus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Monitor Results has been [dropped](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60224) in [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32/). You could consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for monitoring your application metrics
2. With regards to View Results Tree listener issue - most probably your installation is incomplete or corrupt, you can try installing missing components using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Answer (score 1):

This listener has been removed since version 3.2:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html

See related bug:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60423